# Accessing methods which isn't defined

Tags: java

I have a following method `build` defined in another class which is basically making use of the two classes `PD.java` and `SD.java` as mentioned below. The method code is as follows :

```
protected String build(final PD pd) {
    if (pd == null || pd.getField() == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return " ORDER BY " + pd.getFieldName() + ' ' + pd.getDirection().getCommand();
    }
  }
```

**My Questions:**

As shown in `PD.java` below, it has `getDirection()` method defined in it but not `getCommand()`. The `getCommand()` method is defined in `SD.java`. Hence, I am wondering if in the above `build` method, the following way of accessing method is correct or not?

`pd.getDirection().getCommand();`

Please consider the following classes :

Class Name:SD.java

```
public enum SD implements MappableEnum<SD> {

  ASCENDING("A", "Ascending", "ASC"),
  DESCENDING("D", "Descending", "DESC"),

  ;

  private final String code;
  private final String description;
  private final String command;

  private static final Map<String, SD> CODE_MAP =
    MappableEnumUtil.buildCodeMap(SD.class);

  private SD(final String code, final String description, final String command) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.command = command;
  }

  @JsonValue
  @Override
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public SD toEnum(final String code) {
    return fromCode(code);
  }

  public String getCommand() {
    return command;
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static SD fromCode(final String code) {
    return CODE_MAP.get(code);
  }

  public static SD fromCode(final char code) {
    return fromCode(String.valueOf(code));
  }

}
```

Class Name : PD.java

```
public class PD<F extends SF> {

  private final F field;

  private final Integer limit;

  private final Integer offset;

  private final SD direction;

  public PD(final F field, final Integer limit, final Integer offset, final SD direction) {
    this.field = field;
    this.limit = limit;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.direction = direction;
  }

  public F getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return field.getColumnName();
  }

  public Integer getLimit() {
    return limit;
  }

  public Integer getOffset() {
    return offset;
  }

  public SD getDirection() {
    return direction;
  }
}
```

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yes, it does. there are no compilation errors. Do you see anything wrong with the above code?

Comment: Sorry I misread the code at first. Seems fine, are facing any problems? SD is a generic class but you are not depending on the type parameter so it should be ok. (hint: for posting question try to create the smallest code sample that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: @MiserableVariable The problem is that I am expecting my build method to return results via  `pd.getDirection().getCommand();` but it's not returning anything. Do you see anything wrong with apostrophe (single / double) in that line?

Comment: Did you try to step through the code in debugger to see what `build` returns and how the complete query subsequently gets processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SD type is a variable in the PD class, then it can access any public methods that are defined for the SD class. If the visibility of the method in SD is not public, then it will be unable to access that method.

Comment: But in `pd.getDirection().getCommand();`, the `getDirection()` method is accessed by the object of the PD class, `pd` which makes sense, however, the `getCommand()` method is defined inside SD class, so is it legal to access it like this `pd.getDirection().getCommand();` ?

Comment: Yes, since anything that is an instance of a PD is also an instance of SF, such as the effect of polymorphism.

Comment: Why are you including SF here.  I believe it has nothing to do with my question as `getDirection()` belongs to PD class and `getCommand()` belongs to SD class. Or  did you mean to say that since I have `private final SD direction;` defined inside PD class, I can access any methods of SD class just like my question?

Comment: So based on your new description `pd.getDirection().getCommand();` is legal?

Comment: yes it should be since pd.getDirection() returns an instance of SD, and it is declared in SD